# A general question on Mathematical notation: Concerning iff statement

Tags: logic

I am working on a proof where I would like to use the symbol for the if and only if statement. Could anyone write a valid symbol for this logical statement.

Comment: A 2-headed arrow.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if you're just asking for the standard symbol for "iff" it is $\iff$.

Comment: $\iff$ is one, produced by \iff. $\leftrightarrow$ is another, produced by \leftrightarrow.

Answer (score 2):

This is typically denoted by $\leftrightarrow$ or $\iff$.